# Meteor smart packages: Option for the user to pick files/target

Tags: meteor

I'm the maintainer of the Meteor smart package [zipzap](https://atmospherejs.com/package/zipzap) and I would like to understand how a user of that package could possible specify if that package should be used on server, client or both. The package provides zip functionality, both on server and client. But if the user only needs server side zip functionality all files content still would be sent to the client and I don't see a way how to change that other than the user modifies the package.js.

A package.js looks like this:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('path/to/file.js', ['server', 'client']);
});
```

This is hardcoded so the user doesn't have any way to specify which files will be transferred to the client.

I see how my case might not be that common, as most packages either provide functionality for the server **or** client, or in some way interact with each other. But I see the same problem for client side packages which provide multiple features but the user only needs few of them and most of the code therefore never is required. Isn't there a way how the user could interact with the package and say:

- I only need this on server
- Activate feature X
- Disable feature Y

I know the package system is not yet final and is the last big thing to be finished before Meteor 1.0. So it might be that any answer to that question might be obsolete next week. Thought I still ask.

Comment: I believe there's no such possibility at this moment, other than creating separate packages for client and server support. Which probably doesn't make much sense, as both the packaging system and client code loading will get overhaul in the future.

Comment: Even with the new packaging system it is not possible. Not sure how it was before, but at least in the new system, the package.js is not even shipped to the client. The files are added when the package is created. I guess I will have to live with two packages then.